# SwiftでSFSpeechRecognizerとAVSpeechSynthesizerを一つのアプリで行うときのエラー回避方法

Tags: swift, ios, iphone, swift4

Swift4.2での質問です。
SFSpeechRecognizerとAVSpeechSynthesizerを一つのアプリで使うとき、
例えばRecognizeViewControllerで音声認識を行い、SpeechViewControllerのspeechButtonで音声読み上げを行うよう組んだのですが、Thread 1: signal SIGABRTのエラーが出てしまい困っているので質問させていただきます。https://qiita.com/croquette0212/items/bf0e41ca1b65c6d320b4
この記事を読み、AVSessionのsetCategoryによる使い分けを行えばよいと思い、
音声認識処理では録音処理のメソッドに

```
private func startRecording() throws {
    //ここに録音する処理を記述
    if let recognitionTask = recognitionTask {
        //リセット処理
        recognitionTask.cancel()
        self.recognitionTask = nil
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.record, mode: .default)
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.measurement)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    }
}
```

と書き、 SpeechViewControllerの方には

```
var talker = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    //speechButtonの生成処理
    speechButton.addTarget(resultCardView, action: #selector(speachButtonTapped(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside 
}

@objc func speachButtonTapped(sender: Any) {
    let avSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try? avSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient, mode: .default, options: .mixWithOthers)
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string:self.Jplabel.text!)
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-En")
    utterance.volume = 1.2
    // 実行
    self.talker.speak(utterance)
}
```

このように記述したのですが、Thread 1: signal SIGABRTとなってしまいました。
わかる方がいましたら、お願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

`class`宣言と`func`宣言の間に、`var speechButton:UIButton!`（`!`又は`?`）がないため、`speechButton`に格納されているインスタンスが`viewDidLoad()`を抜けると解放されてしまうからではないでしょうか？

```
var talker = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
```

の、次の行に

```
var speechButton:UIButton!
```

を追加し、`speechButton`をクラスのメンバー変数にしてあげ、`viewDidLoad()`の中の`speechButton`の宣言部(`let speechButton`の`let`)を削れば、クラス（のインスタンス）が存在している間は`speechButton`のインスタンスも保持されるので動くようになると思います。

もう一点、

```
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-En")
```

と、ありますが、`language`には、`en-EN`というコードはなく、
`en-US`(アメリカ)、`en-GB`（イギリス）、`en-AU`(オーストラリア）、`en-IE`（アイルランド）、`en-ZA`（南アフリカ）のいずれかを指定する必要があると思います。

また、`setCategory`ですが、`option:`の引数は`[]`となっているので、

```
try? avSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers])
```

ではないでしょうか？

Comment: 行ってみたのですが、やはりThread 1: signal SIGABRTのエラーになってしまいました。　補足としてですが、speechButtonの方の try?の行をコメントアウトすれば、エラーなく動くのですが、音声認識後にspeechButtonをタップすると音が小さくなってしまいます。

Comment: 済みません。`avSession`もメンバー変数にならないといけないとおもいます。これでも落ちるようでしたら、デバッガーで、exception throwにブレークポイントを設定するとどこで落ちているか、より具体的な箇所がわかるかと思います。

Comment: 回答補足しましたので参照下さい